# How to use userscript to replace part of html code?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, userscripts

I would like to install `greasemonkey` to use `userscript` , when loading specific page then insert some code to split table into two part.

I find some resources to teach people to replace html part code here:

http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/135341

If I just replace the part of value, it can be executed correctly. But not one sentence.

Below is what I want to work with:

```
Source:
... 
<TABLE width="370" align="center" border="0" style="font-size:7pt;font:bold">
...
```

I'm going to insert code below,  to be in front of  TABLE

```
</td></tr></tbody></table><table><tbody><tr><td>
```

to make it to look like

```
</td></tr></tbody></table><table><tbody><tr><td><TABLE width="370" align="center" border="0" style="font-size:7pt;font:bold">
```

I read example,  make this work!

```
var HTML = document.body.innerHTML;
HTML = HTML.replace(/width="370"/ig, 'width="380"');
document.body.innerHTML = HTML;
```

it can be successfully replaced by width = "370" width = "380"

but when I try this

```
HTML = HTML.replace(/<TABLE width="370"/ig, '<TABLE width="380"');
```

I get nothing....

Here it's code I was plan to do but it failed too

```
HTML = HTML.replace(/<TABLE width="370"/ig, '<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table><table><tbody><tr><td><TABLE width="380"');
```

Comment: Are you also adding end tags for the table you are creating after the existing table? You may be seeing no result because the browser detects invalid HTML if there are no closing tags.

Comment: I did. It was <table_big>   <table_1> < table_2> </table_big>  I want it to become < table_big > < table_1 > </table_big >   <table_new > < table_2> <table_new>          And,  for test code, I didnt insert or replace any tag,  I'm tring to replace width value only.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [ask] and [mcve]. The [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/tests) site may be helpful.